# Chrome plugin - Send message to content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i'm trying to send a message to my content script from the background, along with the menu ID that was clicked (which works perfectly now). After looking at similair questions i followed the guide from google developer on message passing [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). but it doesnt seem to work for me as i get an uncaught event handler.

**Manifest**

```
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
 ],

"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["scrippy.js"] 
},

 "content_scripts": [
{
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
}
]
}
```

**Background**

```
// Create context menu type variable so that its easily changed for all of them
var type = ["editable"];

// Create context menu
// Parent item
var scrippyMenu = chrome.contextMenus.create({"id": "1", "title": "Scrippy", "contexts": type});

// Child 1
var menuChild1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"id": "2", "title": "child1", "parentId": scrippyMenu, "contexts": type});

// Child 2
var menuChild2 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
{"id": "3", "title": "child2", "parentId": scrippyMenu, "contexts": type});

// sub child 1 of child 2
var menuChild3 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
{"id": "4", "title": "sub child", "parentId": menuChild2, "contexts": type});

// Create an on click event listener and send message to content.js
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {

//check menu item being sent
console.log("Menu item ID: " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");

//Send message to content.js with the current tab id and menuItemId clicked
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {menuId: info.menuItemId},

//On response from content.js log it to console.
function(response) {
if(response.gotIt == "Got it"){
            console.log("Got it!");
}
     });
   });
});
```

**Content**

```
//Listener waiting for messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

console.log(sender.tab ?
            "from a content script:" + sender.menuId : "from the extension");

//if message states menu id of 4 then send response back to background
if (request.menuID == "4") 

sendResponse({gotIt: "Got it"});

});
```

**Error Message**

> extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'gotIt' of undefined

[image: Error message screen grab]

This is a follow up to a previous question i had about context menu's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216536/chrome-plugin-right-click-insert-text). ive created a new question as a result of the answer there and code has changed enough that i think its best to ask a new here.

Comment: Can you include the exact error message?

Comment: Hi @Xan thanks for your help ive added the exact error message and took a screen shot of it just incase, added it to the main post.

Comment: This probably means that the content script is not there to listen in the active tab. How is it injected? Also, do check for `chrome.runtime.lastError` in the callback.

Comment: I am using the run_at option in the manifest file and setting it to end of document so that the rest of the DOM is loaded first. ive update the question with the manifest file and added the rest of my background script as for some reason on the last error its saying that all my menus "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running contextMenus.create: Cannot create item with duplicate id 4" does this for id 1,2 and 3 aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your `content.js`,

```
request.menuID == "4"
```

should be

```
request.menuId == "4"
```

Besides, you could make your `background.js` more robust by checking if response is undefined.

```
if (typeof response !== "undefined" && response.gotIt == "Got it") {
    console.log("Got it!");
}
```

Comment: No, shouldnt be that as i have the permissions set up already. although ive added my manifest file to the question incase there is any issue with that

Comment: This is now correct, but that means the question should be closed as "typo"

Comment: haha Thanks! ive looked at this for hours and never noticed this! how do i close as typo?

Comment: @TweetingGary Well, you could simply delete the question (even though that would rob Haibara of 35 rep). I mean high-rep users should vote to close this question as per #2 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I don't think you can do it yourself.